# Store whole dataset to database

Tags: c#, .net

How to store a complete dataset into database without having to do it table by table and row by row.

Comment: Can you please provide more information about the kinds of data that you would like to store? If you are looking for storage of multiple complete datasets, you might want a document database rather than a relational database (e.g. couch DB).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx). It can do bulk inserts/updates/deletes using its `.Update()` method.

That of course only works if you're using SQL Server as your database - you didn't mention what database you're targeting in your question....

See some tutorials on how to use SqlDataAdapter:

- [ADO.NET Tutorial Lesson 5](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson05.aspx)
- [ASP.NET Quickstart Tutorial - Update database from dataset](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/howto/doc/adoplus/UpdateDataFromDB.aspx)

Marc

Answer (score 0):

You could serialize the dataset to Xml and store it as a string

Comment: Or, you could store XML as XML in SQL Server 2005 or above, with no serialization overhead.

Comment: Puzzien gave no indication of database technology

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little ambiguous, so assuming you want to store multiple objects in a row i would recommend you investigate storing them as serialized json.

serialize the objects before you store them and un-serialize them when you need them again.